Retrieve Top Searches including Clicks
I'm new to working with APIs in Databricks and am struggling with the documentation of Algolia:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/analytics/#tag/search/operation/getTopSearches
I've managed to retrieve the topsearches without any issues. However, I'd also like to retrieve the clicks on the top searched entries.
From what I understand I need to add click_analytics = True when calling the API in DBR:
response = await client.get_top_searches(          
index="prod_de_abc-products_p1",          
click_analytics=True,          
start_date=start_date,          
end_date=start_date      
)

When I do this, I get the same results as when I leave the click_analytics out. What am I missing here?
